# QStyleOptionViewItem.text cannot be changed after the first assignment

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

Please see the following code snippet:

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleOptionViewItem
>>> option = QStyleOptionViewItem()
>>> option.text = '123456'
>>> option.text
'123456'
>>> option.text = '654321'
>>> option.text
'123456'
>>> option.text = 'abcdef'
>>> option.text
'123456'
>>>
```

The `option.text` always keeps the value `123456` which is assigned the first time. But actually, if call the `drawControl` with the changed `option`

```
style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)
```

The `option.text` with new value will be drawn.

Is this a bug or just by design in the Qt5 or PyQt5?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using PyQt-5.7.1, so if it was a bug, it has been fixed now.

Comment: @ekhumoro the version of my PyQt is 5.5.1.  But I just try the Python3.5+PyQt5.7,  still has this issue.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, it has been fixed in PyQt-5.7.1